# Generatingfunctionology Example 2.8

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

This is a bit silly but I am unable to arrive at the conclusion to example 2.8. This is the number of ways that a number can be written as an ordered sum. Wilf shows that

$$f(n,k) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k}}$$

where $f(n,k)$ is the ordered sums of $n$ containing $k$ terms. Wilf concludes:

> By (1.31), $f(n,k) = {n+k-1 \choose n}$

Looking back to 1.31, these are the two main binomial results:

$$ \sum_{k} {n \choose k}x^{k} = (1+x)^n $$

and

$$ \sum_{n} {n \choose k}y^{n} = \frac{y^{k}}{(1-y)^{k+1}} $$

It is not clear, but if I had to guess it is the second result that is relevant. Using this, I get (with some different indices):

$$\frac{x^{p}}{(1-x)^{p+1}} = \sum_{q} {q \choose p}x^{q}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{p+1}} = \sum_{q} {q \choose p}x^{q-p} $$

Continuing, I then substitute $k = p+1$:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k}} = \sum_{q} {q \choose k-1}x^{q-k+1} $$

I can then try to get it to look "like" the result with $n = q - k + 1$:

$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k}} = \sum_{n} {n+k-1 \choose k-1}x^{n} $$

but this is still wrong.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Viewing Example 2.9 which follows shortly after, I am wondering if this might be a typo in the book and I might be correct in my result. In Example 2.9, the problem considers 1/(1-x)^4 and gets the [x^n] coefficient as "n+3 choose 3" which would be consistent with my result setting k = 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$. So we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n} {n+k-1 \choose k-1}x^{n}=\sum_{n} \color{blue}{{n+k-1 \choose n}}x^{n}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.

Comment: Formerly episqrt?

Comment: @FShrike: Formerly epi163sqrt :-)

Comment: Haha, thanks. Very simple final step.

Comment: @PoissonAerohead: Yes, you're right. It wasn't that difficult. :-)